# codeigniter $this->upload->do_upload() = false

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file. I select a file and then I submit it but result of $this->upload->do_upload() is always false.

Here is my form;

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart(base_url('files/fileUpload')); ?>
        <input type="file" name="userfile" class="btn btn-default" size="20"/>
        <input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>
```

and here is my controller;

```
public function __construct() {    
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

public function fileUpload(){
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        var_dump($this->upload->do_upload());die;
}
```

Do I miss something ? What do I need to do ?

Thank you..

Comment: set upload path, `$config['upload_path']` [Refer](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with code in controller fileUpload function

Try with below code

```
public function fileUpload(){
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        var_dump($this->upload->do_upload());die;   
    }
```

Here you need to define file upload path and file allow types.

Hope this will help you.