# do_upload() returns FALSE always codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

Whenever i try to upload images it returns false. 
I've loaded all helpers and libraries as it is working fine in other class, but same code copy is not working in other controller class.

here is the form

```
  <?php          
            echo form_label('Upload file(s)','images[]');
            echo form_error('images[]'); 
            echo form_upload('images[]','','class="form-control" multiple');
     ?>
```

Here is the code in Controller class

```
if(!empty($this->input->post('images'))){
 $config = array(
                'upload_path' => './media/', 
                'file_name' => $title, //creating file name from post title
                'allowed_types' => 'jpg|gif|png',
                'max_size' => '2048',
                'remove_spaces' => TRUE,
                'encrypt_name' => TRUE,
                'overwrite' => TRUE,
                'multi' => 'all'
            );

            $this->load->library('upload', $config); //loading correctly 

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('images')) // returns false
            {var_dump($this->upload->do_upload('images'));
            var_dump($this->upload->display_errors()); //return empty string
            exit;
                $this->data['upload_errors'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
          }
```

What is missing? why it is showing the upload errors as empty string?
I'd a look on this related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579277/codeigniter-this-upload-do-upload-false), but doesn't help.

Comment: You are trying to do it multiple images `[]` you need to google search upload multiple files with codeigniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You recieved files in controller, but in `$this->input->post('images')` is array. You need work with it as with array: `$files = $this->input->post('images');`. Also you can use `foreach` to do actions with `$files`

Comment: Added but no success. Also the uploaded files are receiving in controller, like upon var_dump($this->input->post('images')); the result is array(2) { [0]=> string(20) "floor-house-plan.jpg" [1]=> string(34) "RoomSketcher-House-Floor-Plans.jpg" }

Comment: You recieved files in controller, but in $this->input->post('images') is array. You need work with it as with array: `$files =  $this->input->post('images');` then $files[0] is it first file, $files[1] second ... @Esar-ul-haqQasmi

Comment: Also you can use `foreach` to do actions with all $files

Comment: It helps, Actually the form_open_multipart(); was not added correctly. Now it is working fine. Thanks for the hint.